# Firefox toolbar development, possible to load toolbar into browser as I dev?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I notice for chrome I can load an extension I'm developing into it without packaging it or anything. I'm wondering is this possible to do on FireFox? If not, what's the least painful way to develop and test at the same time? I'm using linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I believe you can perform what is a called a "chrome reload".

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Getting_started_with_extension_development#Development_cycle

Comment: The extension Extension Developer has a button that does this.